# MYSQL - JOIN 2 Tables to get a sorted result

Tags: mysql

I am using this query to import all the 'id_order'

```
INSERT INTO `gf_compta` (ID)
SELECT `gf_order_detail`.id_order
FROM `gf_order_detail`;
```

But I would like to get only the order which 'current_state=4' in the table `gf_orders`

To make it even simplier, I was wondering something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `gf_compta` (ID)
SELECT `gf_order_detail`.id_order
FROM `gf_order_detail`;
JOIN `gf_orders`
WHERE `gf_orders`.current_state=4;
```

But this query is far away from working.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see basic syntax errors here:

```
INSERT INTO `gf_compta` (ID)
SELECT g.id_order
FROM `gf_order_detail` god
JOIN `gf_orders` g on g.<someColumn>=god.<somecolumn>
WHERE g.current_state=4;
```

UPDATED

```
INSERT INTO `gf_compta` (ID)
SELECT g.id_order
FROM `gf_orders` g
JOIN  `gf_order_detail` god on g.id_order=god.id_order
AND g.current_state=4;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: can you give some example of your table data?

Comment: Sure, please find the 2 concerned tables,[gf_orders](https://www.geffenstore.fr/gf_orders.csv)
[gf_order_detail](https://www.geffenstore.fr/gf_order_detail.csv)

Comment: Which is the parent table?
Which column shows the relation of these two tables with one another?

Comment: The column that shows the relation between them is the column Id_order

Comment: See my updated answer